# Windows 8 click event hander only works once WinJS

Tags: html, windows-8, winjs

I'm coding a Windows 8 application in JavaScript and HTML5.  I wish to show a dialog box when clicking a button.

I have specified the event handler in the `default.js` file like so:

```
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232509
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
    WinJS.strictProcessing();

    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
                // your application here.

            } else {
                // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
                // Restore application state here.
            }
            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().done(function () {

                // Get the login button on the home page
                var login_button = document.getElementById("login_submit");

                // Set an event handler on the login button
                login_button.addEventListener("click", UserActionLogin, false);

            }));
        }
    };

    app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
        // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state
        // that needs to persist across suspensions here. You might use the
        // WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically
        // saved and restored across suspension. If you need to complete an
        // asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call
        // args.setPromise().
    };

    function UserActionLogin(mouseEvent) {

        var message_dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Sorry, we were unable to log you in!" + mouseEvent.y.toString()).showAsync();
    }

    app.start();
})();
```

My HTML markup is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>HelloWorld</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- HelloWorld references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="login_box">
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="login_username" />
            <input type="password" name="login_password" />
            <input type="submit" id="login_submit" name="login_submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the `login_submit` button when the application loads, it shows the dialog box just fine.

But when I click it for a second time it doesn't work, it's like it's forgotten about the Event Handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is having the  element in there, which you don't need in an app because you won't want to have the submit button repost/reload the page with the form contents. You're effectively reloading the page but the activated handler isn't called in that case (the page is loaded as a post rather than a request), so you lose the event handler.

If you delete the  element, then it works just fine. I'm also told that if you use type="button" instead of type="submit" then it should work. But in an app, you'll typically collect the data from the controls and save that in other variables, navigating to another "page" in the app using the WInJS navigation and page control mechanisms, which keeps you on default.html without changing script context.

Also, I notice that you're still referring to the RC version of WinJS. Since Win8 is officially released now, be sure to develop against the released version of the system and using the most recent tools.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your use of the `form` element, which is causing your HTML to be reloaded when you click the button - this replaces the element you set up the event handler for, meaning that subsequent clicks don't invoke your handler function.

Remove the form element and you will get the behavior you expect, as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App7</title>

    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/ui.js"></script>

    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="login_box">
        <input type="text" name="login_username" />
        <input type="password" name="login_password" />
        <input type="submit" id="login_submit" name="login_submit" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you really need the `form` element for some reason (perhaps because you are using a JS library which expects it), then you can prevent the problem by stopping the form being submitted in your event handler function, as follows:

```
function UserActionLogin(mouseEvent) {
    var message_dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Sorry, we were unable to log you in!" + mouseEvent.y.toString()).showAsync();
    mouseEvent.preventDefault();
}
```

The call to  preventDefault stops the form being posted but allows you to keep the form element in the document.